# сохранить модель tensorflow( tf.estimator.Estimator )

Tags: python, model, export, tensorflow

Помогите пожалуйста сохранить модель, Estimator.

есть такая функция `model.export_savedmodel(export_dir_base, serving_input_receiver_fn, assets_extra=None, as_text=False, checkpoint_path=None, strip_default_attrs=False)`

export_dir_base - тут все понятно

serving_input_receiver_fn - вот это главный затык, я уже помотрел и документацию и примеры.

вот такой пример я смог найти на просторах интернета, но не смог его адаптировать для себя:

ссылка на тему где обсуждали: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12508

```
def estimator(model_path):
    feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(INPUT_TENSOR_NAME, shape=[4])]
    return tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                      hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
                                      n_classes=3,
                                      model_dir=model_path)


def serving_input_receiver_fn():
    feature_spec = {INPUT_TENSOR_NAME: tf.FixedLenFeature(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[4])}
    return tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_spec)()


def train_input_fn(training_dir):
    training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(
        filename=os.path.join(training_dir, 'iris_training.csv'),
        target_dtype=np.int,
        features_dtype=np.float32)

    return tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
        x={INPUT_TENSOR_NAME: np.array(training_set.data)},
        y=np.array(training_set.target),
        num_epochs=None,
        shuffle=True)()
```

помогите , пожалуйста, разобраться, насколько я понимаю, проблема актуальна и там что-то добавили только 1.6 что бы это стало проще.

```
    #CONVOLUTIONAL NEURAL NETWORK
from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import


# Training Parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
num_steps = 100
batch_size = 128

# Network Parameters
num_input = 196 # systoles data input (img shape: 14*14)
num_classes = 19 # systoles total classes (0-19 digits)
dropout = 0.25 # Dropout, probability to drop a unit


# Create the neural network
def conv_net(x_dict, n_classes, dropout, reuse, is_training):
    # Define a scope for reusing the variables
    with tf.variable_scope('ConvNet', reuse=reuse):
        # TF Estimator input is a dict, in case of multiple inputs
        x = x_dict['images']

        # systoles data input is a 1-D vector of 196 features (14*14 pixels)
        # Reshape to match picture format [Height x Width x Channel]
        # Tensor input become 4-D: [Batch Size, Height, Width, Channel]
        x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 1, 196, 1])

        # Convolution Layer with 16 filters and a kernel size of 4
        conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(x, filters=16, kernel_size= [1,4], activation=tf.nn.relu)
        # Max Pooling (down-sampling) with strides of 2 and kernel size of 2
        conv1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv1, pool_size=[1,2], strides = [1,2])

        # Convolution Layer with 32 filters and a kernel size of 2
        conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv1, filters=32,  kernel_size= [1,2], activation=tf.nn.relu)
        # Max Pooling (down-sampling) with strides of 2 and kernel size of 2
        conv2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv2, pool_size=[1,2], strides = [1,2])

        # Flatten the data to a 1-D vector for the fully connected layer
        fc1 = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(conv2)

        # Fully connected layer (in tf contrib folder for now)
        fc1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs= fc1, units= 2048, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        # Apply Dropout (if is_training is False, dropout is not applied)
        fc1 = tf.layers.dropout(fc1, rate=dropout, training=is_training)

        # Output layer, class prediction
        out = tf.layers.dense(fc1, n_classes)

    return out


# Define the model function (following TF Estimator Template)
def model_fn(features, labels, mode):
    # Build the neural network
    # Because Dropout have different behavior at training and prediction time, we
    # need to create 2 distinct computation graphs that still share the same weights.
    logits_train = conv_net(features, num_classes, dropout, reuse=False,
                            is_training=True)
    logits_test = conv_net(features, num_classes, dropout, reuse=True,
                           is_training=False)

    # Predictions
    pred_classes = tf.argmax(logits_test, axis=1)
    pred_probas = tf.nn.softmax(logits_test)

    # If prediction mode, early return
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, predictions=pred_classes)

        # Define loss and optimizer
    loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
        logits=logits_train, labels=tf.cast(labels, dtype=tf.int32)))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op,
                                  global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())

    # Evaluate the accuracy of the model
    acc_op = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels, predictions=pred_classes)

    # TF Estimators requires to return a EstimatorSpec, that specify
    # the different ops for training, evaluating, ...
    estim_specs = tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode=mode,
        predictions=pred_classes,
        loss=loss_op,
        train_op=train_op,
        eval_metric_ops={'accuracy': acc_op})

    return estim_specs

# Build the Estimator
model = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn)

# Define the input function for training
input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x={'images': x_train}, 
                                              y= y_train, 
                                              batch_size=batch_size, 
                                              num_epochs=None, 
                                              shuffle=True)
# Train the Model
model.train(input_fn, steps=num_steps)

# Evaluate the Model
# Define the input function for evaluating
input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x={'images': x_eval}, 
                                              y= y_eval, 
                                              batch_size=batch_size, 
                                              shuffle=False)
# Use the Estimator 'evaluate' method

e = model.evaluate(input_fn)

print("Testing Accuracy:", e['accuracy'])#95


model.export_savedmodel()# ????
```

`model.export_savedmodel()# ????`  как правильно и что передать этой функции?

другие варианты сохранения я знаю, они работают на других моделях, было очень интересно разобраться именно с сохранением Estimator.

[ссылка от MaxU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45640951/tensorflow-classifier-export-savedmodel-beginner/48329456#48329456), Проверил вариант:

```
    def serving_input_receiver_fn():
    serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string, shape=[None], name='input_tensors')
    receiver_tensors      = {"predictor_inputs": serialized_tf_example}
    feature_spec          = {"images": tf.FixedLenFeature([19],tf.float32)}
    features              = tf.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, feature_spec)
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, receiver_tensors)

full_model_dir = model.export_savedmodel(export_dir_base= r"/savedmodel",                                                  
                     serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn)



# >>>> ValueError: export_outputs must be a dict and not<class 'NoneType'>
```

это я еще поправил, там сходу ошибка, в том варианте он в tf.FixedLenFeature - передает int , а можно только float, это як тому что это только теоретический вариант, скорей всего.

возможно в `serialized_tf_example`  надо передавать что-то от моей модели?

Comment: [Так пробовали?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48329456/5741205)

Comment: попытался подставить, но выдает ошибку:# ValueError: export_outputs must be a dict and not  в конце вопроса дописал как проверял.